# How to hide/remove the 3 dots of a Sharepoint document library in Sharepoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have put a document library on my wikipage. And i have customize the view of the document library so that only the icon and title will be displayed. But also the 3 dots will be displayed. How can I hide this or remove this?

Comment: They are related to which type of variant of the default Title column your view has. Change the column from ”linked to item (with edit menu) to linked to item and they are gone.

Comment: That is the weardest thing I have unchecked "Name linked to item (with edit menu)" and have checked the item Naam linked to document. But the dots are still there.

Comment: As long as you have the title "linked" to the item, the three dots will show.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the view and out of the three variants for the Title column, select the one that is NOT linked to the title. It's the link to the item that creates the "more options" functionality.

Of course, if you don't have the title linked to the item, your users won't be able to open the item and will only see the grid view, not the item details.

Comment: I have 3 options: Name (linked to document) , Name (linked to document with menu) and Name (linked to form). All 3 options doesn't work. I guess its not possible :)

Answer (score 0):

Here're two methods.

1.Select and display the "Title" column instead of Title (linked to item with edit menu) and use Name (linked to document) column if you want to open the document on click of name.

2.Use this method can control this in a single view by controlling the access.

Create a custom permission level where remove the "Edit" permission and assign this custom permission in item level for the users, so that users will not get edit option or three dots.